# Send json by ajax - Object - object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have problem with send json by AJAX.

```
var data = [{"name": "Will", "surname": "Smith", "age": "40"},{"name": "Willow", "surname": "Smith", "age": "15"}];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
     echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

And ajax alert response is`[object Object]`

How to get array in php side?

Comment: whats the reponse of ajax in console.

Comment: You have to convert `data` to string by `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `data` to `string` by `JSON.stringify` method and place it into an object. Somehow like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"data": JSON.stringify(data)},
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Then on server-side you can access passed data by `$_POST['data']`:

```
echo json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: Now this works, json is sending.
How to get this json by php side as array?

Comment: You could upvote this answer as well if it solve your problem

Comment: im getting parse error with
<?php
    $data = json_decode($_POST,true); 
     echo $data;
?>